# How to use Ninject property injection from UITableViewController?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, ninject

I am using Portable.Ninject in a xamarin.iOS app and I would like to inject my services on properties.
[Inject] on the property doesn't work because the viewController isn't created by Ninject.

How can I use Ninject property injection in UITableViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `kernel.Inject(myFooInstance)` to have ninject perform property injection on existing objects. The properties still need the `[Inject]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I will call kernel.Inject inside the constructor and mark my properties with [Inject].